# Flexbox align several items to left, several to the center and several to the right - order should be changeable

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

I need a CSS solution for the following case:

I have a header with several children, say four. Not all four children have an equal width. Items are by default aligned to the left. I use `margin-left` and/or `margin-right` auto to align items to the center/right. I change the order of the items with the CSS `order` property.

Now I want to align items to the left, center and right of the container. The order of the children should change on viewports (using `@media` queries).

How do I center an unspecified number of items to the left, to the center and to the right, in different viewport widths?

My (simplified) HTML

```
<div class="header-container">

 <div class="first-child">
 </div>
 <div class="second-child">
 </div>
 <div class="third-child">
 </div>
 <div class="fourth-child">
 </div>

</div>
```

I've also put my simplified situation in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ralphsmit/j4fqreos/6/).

**Concrete example of look with viewports**

```
@media (max-width: 799px) {*

 left: first-child and second-child

 center: third-child

 right: fourth-child

}

@media (max-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1319px) {

 left: third-child

 center: first-child and second-child

 right: fourth-child

}

@media (min-width: 1320px) {

 left: first-child

 center: third-child

 right: second-child

 fourth-child - display: none;

}
```

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D thanks for reminding that. I've searched a lot for this problem, but haven't found a solution yet. I did not add my code, because I did not want to 'push' people in the wrong direction. I'm open to all kind of solution and not one specific thing I've tried.

Comment: That's why I put it in the JSFiddle; I've now added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you will have to group childs that are for example in the middle:

```
<div class="grouped-items">
  <div class="second-child">
  </div>
  <div class="third-child">
  </div>
</div>
```

After that, you will have three groups of items or separate items. Use `justify-content: space-between`

It would look like this (open in full page to see best result):

```css
.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 68px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* Set display: flex so they will act same as if they weren't in another div */

.grouped-items {
  display: flex;
}

.first-child {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.second-child {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.third-child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.fourth-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 799px) {
  .grouped-items {
    order: 1;
  }
  .third-child {
    order: 2;
  }
  .fourth-child {
    order: 3;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1319px) {
  .grouped-items {
    order: 2;
  }
  .third-child {
    order: 1;
  }
  .fourth-child {
    order: 3;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1320px) {
  .fourth-child {
    display: none;
  }

  .grouped-items {
    order: 2;
  }
  .third-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">

  <div class="grouped-items">
    <div class="first-child">
    </div>
    <div class="second-child">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="third-child">
  </div>

  <div class="fourth-child">
  </div>

</div>
```

To change order on media, just use `order`

Comment: Hi @Vepthy thanks for your solution! Unfortunately the sets of grouped items are also not fixed, they are also changeable.

Comment: Orders are changeable. Point is that you if you want to make left-center-right layout, you will need to do space-between and make 3 groups. You can change orders afterwards. Though, you won't be able to change layout of each group, only with javascript

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the layout is not changeable, except with JS? Because that's in fact my problem..

Comment: @ralphsmit you can change how the layout will look. You can't ungroup divs (`second-child` and `third-child` that are in `grouped-items`) without using JS. As you wanted in your question, you can change what will be on left, middle and right side. Also you can do that with @media queries

Comment: @ralphsmit I have changed my code to be more precise to your question.

Comment: Hi @Vepthy I've changed my code to do it a bit differently. Because there's no answer to my problem with only CSS and you spent some time on it, I marked your answer as correct. Cheers, Ralph

Comment: @ralphsmit Did you do it with grid layout? I wanted to tell you that you can actually do that with grid. Notify me so I can change my question for future visitors.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion for css grid. I’m building for Wordpress and therefore I wanted users to be able to rearrange the header layout, for the left, center and right. But I only have three things to rearrange: logo, menu (or hamburger icon) and search icon. Of those three, I figured out that it would only be logical for the logo to be in the center, so I added a control for users to put the logo in the middle. That control removes the logo from the regular flow and centers it with position: absolute. So I did not really change my code, but my needs.

Comment: I don’t want to use CSS-grid, because it’s quite new and does not yet have very wide browser support (AFAIK). I want as much browser support as possible with this project.